# Regex to keep empty parts in the same group index

Tags: regex, regex-group

## Context

I have a string sequence in which some parts can either be empty, or contain information. I'm looking for a regex in which each information is always on the same group index, regardless of if it's empty or not.

The expected benefit is that group indexes remain the same even if a group is empty, so I can say that this or that information is in this or that group.

## Examples

Possible inputs and expected group outputs:

```
1. Input: ABC_0000_0.0.0.xyz
Group 1  : ABC
Group 2  : 0000
Group 3  : 0.0.0
Group 4  : <empty>
Group 5  : <empty>

2. Input: ABC_0001_0.1.0_N.xyz
Group 1  : ABC
Group 2  : 0001
Group 3  : 0.1.0
Group 4  : _N
Group 5  : <empty>

3. Input: ABC_0002_1.1.2_foo.xyz
Group 1  : ABC
Group 2  : 0002
Group 3  : 1.1.2
Group 4  : <empty>
Group 5  : _foo

4. Input: ABC_0002_42.42.42_N_bar.xyz
Group 1  : ABC
Group 2  : 0002
Group 3  : 42.42.42
Group 4  : _N
Group 5  : _bar
```

## What I tried

I tried the following regex:

```
^(ABC)_([0-9]{4})_([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(_[a-zA-Z]+)?(_[a-zA-Z]+)?\.xyz$
```

The problem with that one is that I only have 5 groups for example **4**. For example **1** there are only 3 groups, and for examples **2-3** there are 4 groups but the fourth may contain two different types of information.

I then tried to adapt the part supposed to catch groups 4 and 5 by using a **logical or** to match with emptyness:

```
^(ABC)_([0-9]{4})_([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(|_[a-zA-Z]+)(|_[a-zA-Z]+)\.xyz$
```

This is promising, it works for all examples but example **2**, in which `_N` is put in group 5, while I want it to be in group 4.

## Question

Which regex would, for the examples given, output the same groups ?

Comment: How is group 4 different from group 5?

Comment: @vrintle they can contain the same kind of string, both are of type `(_[a-zA-Z]+)` and can also be empty.

Comment: @Tim Then you cannot require `_foo` to be in Group 5 instead of Group 4 in Example 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(ABC)_([0-9]{4})_([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(?:(_[a-zA-Z]+)(|_[a-zA-Z]+))?\.xyz$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pszJge/1)

Now, due to `(?:(_[a-zA-Z]+)(|_[a-zA-Z]+))?`, Group 5 will only match after Group 4 is matched:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(_[a-zA-Z]+)` - Group 4: `_` and one or more letters
  - `(|_[a-zA-Z]+) - Group 5: empty string or` _` and one or more letters
- `)?` - end of the non-capturing group, one or zero repetitions (due to `?`).

If Group 4 can only have one letter use

```js
^(ABC)_([0-9]{4})_([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(_[a-zA-Z])?(_[a-zA-Z]+)?\.xyz$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pszJge/2).

Now, due to `(_[a-zA-Z])?`, Group 4 will only match a single letter after `_` before Group 5.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me, however there is a mistake in example 3, as `_foo` is caught in group 4 instead of group 5.

Comment: @Tim But why is it a mistake? How do you define Group 4  and Group 5 patterns?

Comment: @Tim Please retry with the solution above. Please let know if it is working for you.

Comment: Because I want to have exactly the same output as in my examples. Here, the output is different. Imagine that group 4 can contain `_N` or be empty, and that group 5 can contain `_foo`, `_bar` or be empty. If later in the SW I want to analyze what's inside group 5, it won't work if `_foo` ends up in group 4, as in your regex demo for example 3.

Comment: @Tim The current answer is the best you can get with your current requirements.

Comment: Thank you, now it works perfectly, with the limitation that group 4 can have only one letter. I'm fine with that ! I'd be curious to know if there's a way to make it work with more letters, but I'm happy with that already. `N` is not for North, I just used fake letters to make it more straightforward and less related with my company, but I kept the same scheme.